# How do I pass an async function to a thread target in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following code:

```py
async some_callback(args):
    await some_function()
```

and I need to give it to a Thread as a target:

```py
_thread = threading.Thread(target=some_callback, args=("some text"))
_thread.start()
```

The error that I get is "`some_callback` is never awaited".
Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What scenarios necessitate passing an asyncio Task to a thread?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can do it by adding function between to execute async:

```py
import asyncio

async def some_callback(args):
    await some_function()

def between_callback(args):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    loop.run_until_complete(some_callback(args))
    loop.close()

_thread = threading.Thread(target=between_callback, args=("some text"))
_thread.start()
```

Comment: What scenarios necessitate passing an asyncio Task to a thread?

Comment: Won't the thread be blocked by python GIL?

Comment: Thread will be blocked if you run CPU-bound code. Thread will not be blocked with IO-bound code or sleep.

Comment: Ok, can you describe your usecase or scenario where you found it useful to run asyncio tasks on threads?

Comment: Example usage: create threads in asyncio can be only one way to run legacy code (when same function/library to run with asyncio not exists yet).

Comment: How can we pass a WebSocket object

Answer (score 75):

As of Python 3.7, you can use `asyncio.run()` which is a bit more straightforward than `loop.run_until_complete()`:

```
_thread = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(some_callback("some text"),))
_thread.start()
```

Comment: How does this actually launch something in a thread? It looked strange to me, and then I tested it and the `some_callback` does indeed execute *before* you start the thread, like it looks like it is going to. You know, because you are calling a sync function and all. No?

Comment: @anton Not sure to understand the question. `some_callback("some_text")` returns a coroutine object, see [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines): "simply calling a coroutine will not schedule it to be executed" and "To actually run a coroutine, asyncio provides three main mechanisms", among which `asyncio.run`. In my answer, `asyncio.run` is the target of the thread and takes the coroutine object returned by the `some_callback` function as argument, it is therefore executed in the thread

Comment: sure, not sure what my thinking was back then but 3 months ago I was still struggling to come to terms with async (even more than now anyway!) so probably was trying to pass a normal function. Anyway, sorry for the noise!

Comment: This might be problematic because the coroutine is created in a different event loop than the loop in which it is run. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70225945), while more verbose, is probably better.

Comment: [ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68431205/typeerror-asyncio-runners-run-argument-after-must-be-an-iterable-not-corou)

Answer (score 3):

After Python 3.7, you can use asyncio.run()

```
import asyncio
import threading

async def some_callback(args):
    await some_function()

def wrap_async_func(args):
    asyncio.run(some_callback(args))

_thread = threading.Thread(target=wrap_async_func, args=("some text"))
_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't quite work for me, if you are trying to let it run next to your code (example: discord wait for emote reaction aswell as add emotes), you could try to use:

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(FUNKTION(ARGUMENT))
```

Answer (score 1):

**[mar-2024]** this work for me.

```py
import asyncio

async def __main(num1: int, num2: int):
  tasks = []
  tasks.append(print1(num1))
  tasks.append(print2(num2))
  print('starting main()')
  # Run the tasks concurrently
  await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

  # above could be more simplier
  task1 = asyncio.create_task(print1)
  task2 = asyncio.create_task(print2)
  await task1
  await task2
```

And invoke the async function like this:

```py
import threading

def run():
  # new thread
  thread = threading.Thread()
  thread.target = asyncio.run(__main(1, 2))
  thread.run() # or thread.start()
```

there's no need to pass args. I suppose within the synchronous context `asyncio.run` runs normally as synchronous. The Async behavioir is implicit in the line where the `await ...` declaration is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your async function with this method and run the thread. **_target** is name of function in string and ****args** all your args. in addition to Norbeck solution

```
def middleware_callback(**args,_target):
_proc = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
_proc.run_until_complete(getattr(sys.modules[__name__], _target)(**args)
_proc.close()
```

Comment: this is a horrible implementation, it has errors. please do not use this