# Start an async function inside a new thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create a discord bot and I need to run an async function in another new Thread since the main Thread is required to run another function (Discord Client)

What I'm trying to accomplish:

```py
# This methods needs to run in another thread
async def discord_async_method():
    while True:
        sleep(10)
        print("Hello World")
        ... # Discord Async Logic

# This needs to run in the main thread
client.run(TOKEN)

thread = ""

try:
    # This does not work, throws error "printHelloWorld Needs to be awaited"
    thread = Thread(target=discord_async_method)
    thread.start()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):

    # Stop Thread when CTRL + C is pressed or when program is exited
    thread.join()
```

I have tried other solutions with asyncio but I couldn't get the other solutions to work.

Followup: When you create a Thread, how do you stop that thread when you stop the program i.e. KeyboardInterupt or SystemExit?

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to involve threads to run two things in parallel in asyncio. Simply submit the coroutine to the event loop as a task before firing up the client.

Note that your coroutine must not run blocking calls, so instead of calling `sleep()` you need to await `asyncio.sleep()`. (This is generally the case with coroutines, not just ones in discord.)

```
async def discord_async_method():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        print("Hello World")
        ... # Discord Async Logic

# run discord_async_method() in the "background"
asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(discord_async_method())

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Would you need to use multi-processing if you needed to do a blocking call in the background or in parallel?

Comment: @WaqasAbbasi No need for multiprocessing, threading will be enough (and much more lightweight). Asyncio provides a convenience function, [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor), for precisely the purpose of running legacy blocking code (or CPU-bound code) from an async function without blocking the event loop.

Answer (score 5):

This also works for me:

```
def entrypoint(*params):
    asyncio.run(discord_async_method(*params))

t = threading.Thread(target=entrypoint, args=(param,), daemon=True)
```

Comment: I want to queue multiple asyncio tasks on the event loop, then wait for all of them to complete from the main thread.
How?