# How to start async target inside thread

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I'm using the [pyCraft](https://github.com/ammaraskar/pyCraft) library to make a bridge with discord and minecraft and I've been  trying multiple solutions like the [asyncio loop thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151031/start-an-async-function-inside-a-new-thread) but when ran it just runs the minecraft client and doesn't start the discord client until I do a keyboard interrupt. The only way I can figure out how this could work is with threading. This function needs to be async because it uses the `await ctx.send` method to send to a channel. I also need to have discord and the function be able to interact with each other. Asyncio:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from minecraft import authentication
from minecraft.exceptions import YggdrasilError
from minecraft.networking.connection import Connection
from minecraft.networking.packets import Packet, clientbound, serverbound

client = discord.Client()

async def mcClient(server='mc.hypixel.net', username='minecraft email', password='password', *, port=25565, version=340):
    # version 340 - Minecraft 1.12.2
    if password is None:
        print("Connecting in offline mode...")
        connection = Connection(
            server, port, username=username)
    else:
        auth_token = authentication.AuthenticationToken()
        try:
            auth_token.authenticate(username, password)
        except YggdrasilError as e:
            print(e)
            sys.exit()
        print("(Online) Logged in as %s..." % auth_token.username)
        connection = Connection(
            server, port, auth_token=auth_token, initial_version=version)

    # listener on join game
    def handle_join_game(join_game_packet):
        print('Connected.')
    
    connection.register_packet_listener(
        handle_join_game, clientbound.play.JoinGamePacket)
    
    # print chat
    def handle_chat(chat_packet):
        cpke = chat_packet.json_data
        print(f"Chat: {cpke}")
        channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
        await channel.send(cpke)

    connection.register_packet_listener(
        handle_chat, clientbound.play.ChatMessagePacket)

    connection.connect()

    # listen for input and send message
    while True:
        try:
            text = input()
            packet = serverbound.play.ChatPacket()
            packet.message = text
            connection.write_packet(packet)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Exiting client.")
            sys.exit()

asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(mcClient())
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Threading (without async):

```
import discord
import threading
from minecraft import authentication
from minecraft.exceptions import YggdrasilError
from minecraft.networking.connection import Connection
from minecraft.networking.packets import Packet, clientbound, serverbound

client = discord.Client()

def mcClient(server='mc.hypixel.net', username='minecraft email', password='password', *, port=25565, version=340):
    # version 340 - Minecraft 1.12.2
    if password is None:
        print("Connecting in offline mode...")
        connection = Connection(
            server, port, username=username)
    else:
        auth_token = authentication.AuthenticationToken()
        try:
            auth_token.authenticate(username, password)
        except YggdrasilError as e:
            print(e)
            sys.exit()
        print("(Online) Logged in as %s..." % auth_token.username)
        connection = Connection(
            server, port, auth_token=auth_token, initial_version=version)

    # listener on join game
    def handle_join_game(join_game_packet):
        print('Connected.')
    
    connection.register_packet_listener(
        handle_join_game, clientbound.play.JoinGamePacket)
    
    # print chat
    def handle_chat(chat_packet):
        cpke = chat_packet.json_data
        print(f"Chat: {cpke}")

    connection.register_packet_listener(
        handle_chat, clientbound.play.ChatMessagePacket)

    connection.connect()

    # listen for input and send message
    while True:
        try:
            text = input()
            packet = serverbound.play.ChatPacket()
            packet.message = text
            connection.write_packet(packet)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Exiting client.")
            sys.exit()

x = threading.Thread(target=mcClient(), daemon=True)
x.start()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

While this works, I can't send messages or do anything discord-related. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I put the whole function and subfunctions to make it easier to understand

Comment: try to add `await` behind the function you're calling.

Comment: I can't await it because the thread is not being started in an asynchronous function. I tried putting this in an async function but it returned "function object cannot be awaited"

Answer (score 0):

`asyncio.gather` might help.

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import pyCraft

client = discord.Client()

async def mcClient():
  # stuff
  global connection
  connection = pyCraft.connection(args)
  connection.connect()

async def handle_chat():
  # send message to discord here
  # because of the global statement, you can reference connection from here too!
  pass

asyncio.gather(mcClient(), handle_chat())
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: what does `gather()` do

Comment: @WindowsIsCool `asyncio.gather` runs two coroutines in parallel so that Discord can interact with Minecraft.

Comment: I made an edit to the original post and I'm still not sure how to completely implement this because I need to define a listener. also, can i turn the function into a class and call its subfunctions or something like that

Comment: also you can't call the function with () or it will call it as its running that line