# How to use asyncio.wait_for to run_until_complete to synchronously call async method in Python

Tags: python, websocket, async-await, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

To allow timeouts receiving data via Python *websocket*, the [FAQ: How do I set a timeout on recv()?](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html) recommends using asynchronously receive data:

```
await asyncio.wait_for(websocket.recv(), timeout=10)
```

Since the function I receive data is not async, I've adapted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59645689/5235574) to run the *asyncio* loop until data was received or the timeout occurred:

```
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=10))
```

Unfortunately this statement seems to be not valid, since the following exception occurs:

> An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

For me, it looks like `asyncio.wait_for` is no valid parameter for the `run_until_complete` although the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) clearly shows an example which `await`s for it.

What am I missing here - and what would be the correct way to use `asyncio.wait_for` in a synchronous method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common websocket modules available in Python.
While [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) is imported with `import websockets` there is also the [websocket-client](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/) which is imported with `import websocket`.

Both of the modules offering nearly the same API where `ws.recv()` allows to receive data.

The fact the modules are so similar to each other may cause confusion which at least lead to my exception.

**While *websockets* are capable of async operations, *websocket* is not**. This means my statement

```
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=10))
```

will only work for *websockets*, if used with *websocket*, the exception

> An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

will occur.

Answer (score 2):

You need to feed `loop.run_until_complete` with a coroutine. To do so, you can wrap your receiving code into an async function:

```py
async def receive_message():
    return await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=10)

loop.run_until_complete(receive_message())
```

Here's a fully working code:

```py
import asyncio
import websockets

URI = "ws://0.0.0.0:8765"
TIMEOUT = 2

async def create_ws():
    return await websockets.connect(URI)

async def receive_message():
    ws = await create_ws()
    print("Connected")
    message = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=TIMEOUT)
    print(f"Received message in less than {TIMEOUT} seconds: {message}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(receive_message())
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. Exactly the same exception occurs.

Comment: I edited my answer with a fully working code (Python 3.6). Please add more code to your question so that we can see if the error comes from somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, I was able to solve the problem. Thanks for your help, this was a good hint to deeper dig in here.