# Running Async task with aiohttp web server using asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp, event-loop

I'm having a small web server that that i'm trying to run async functions on web request:

```
from aiohttp import web
import asyncio

    async def funcB():
        while True:
              print("running")
    
    async def funcA(req):
        print('start')
        asyncio.Task(funcB())
        print('execute task completed')
        return web.Response(text="OK Start");
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    
        app = web.Application()
        app.add_routes([web.get('/', funcA)])
        web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=2000)
```

Once running the app and triggering it by `curl http://127.0.0.1:2000/` i do get the `execute task completed` logline, but the curl response of the curl is not been received, if I comment out the `asyncio.Task(funcB())` line - I do get the response of the CURL command - I must say that funcB dose run..

what do I miss here?

Comment: I am getting curl response in both cases. also, funcB keeps running in your case because of infinite while loop.

Comment: @SajanGohil But that's the case, I'm looking for a way to run an infinite loop in different task / thread ..

Comment: ok, but I can't reproduce your original issue of not getting a curl response

Comment: `asyncio.Task(funcB())` doesn’t actually run your task, it just creates a `Task` object. That’s why your problem can’t be reproduced. That said, your actual problem is that `funcB` never yields back to the event loop. Either it needs to await something they does, or you should use a separate thread or process, depending on whether it’s I/O or CPU bound.

Comment: @dirn hmm... i was under the assumption that this create a new thread - i saw it return a future - if thats not the case how shell i spin funcB in a separated thread?

Comment: Found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645272/how-do-i-pass-an-async-function-to-a-thread-target-in-python