# How to run CPU bound async function in separate thread with asyncio.to_thread?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm making multiple calls to a 3rd party lib using asyncio tasks, wrapped in a function run_task, which is CPU intensive.

I tried using asyncio.to_thread to run it in a separate thread but I am getting errors

Here is a simplified, correct version of my code, using shazamio.

```
import asyncio
from shazamio import Shazam

async def run_task(shazam):
    ret = await asyncio.to_thread(shazam.recognize_song, '01 - Forest Drive West - Impulse.mp3')
    print(ret)
    return 1 

async def run_all_tasks(iters):
    shazam = Shazam()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    coros = [run_task(shazam) for i in range(iters)]
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)
    return 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(run_all_tasks(10))
```

With this I get ret is a coroutine, so the await did not work. I also get these warnings

```
<coroutine object Shazam.recognize_song at 0x11054bf10>
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py:1936: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Shazam.recognize_song' was never awaited
  handle = self._ready.popleft()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: [`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread) takes a function as an argument, not a coroutine. It's `asyncio.to_thread(shazam.recognize_song, 'SomeFile.mp3')`

Comment: Thanks, I corrected this mistake and but i still don't understand the behaviour. I edited the question so that it is clearer and general

Comment: I'm finding that i get the correct behaviour when i replace the `shazam.recognize_song` by time.sleep, but with asyncio.sleep i get the same weird behaviour and warning

Comment: Oh `shazam.recognize_song` does return a coroutine that you could just `await` already? Then you should not use `to_thread` at all! `asyncio.to_thread` takes a synchronous function as its argument, not a coroutine function.

Comment: Yes, you are right. To clarify, I want to run this async function on separate threads. Since recognize_song is CPU bound, using `await` takes as much time as synchronous execution

Comment: I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645272/how-do-i-pass-an-async-function-to-a-thread-target-in-python

Comment: I found the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645272/how-do-i-pass-an-async-function-to-a-thread-target-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error you are getting says is that the `.recognize_song` itself is already written as a co-routine. (and indeed it is, as can be seen in the docs: https://github.com/dotX12/ShazamIO )

On the other hand. the `.to_thread` call expect to receive regular Python functions it will spawn another thread and run there, (and retrieve the return value by using some internal mechanism).

What is taking place is that `.to_thread` is called, it calls the co-routine method `.recognize_song`, which imediatelly returns an awaitable object - `.to_thread` doesn't check it, and return it as the result of calling the "blockin" method.

The fix in this case is trivial: just await for the `shazam.recognize_song` call directly.

BTW, this is not a "CPU intensive task" locally: what it does is to use the Shazam API to remotely identify your song- it is as I/O bound as it can. The remote API, yes, will do CPU intensive work, but on remote CPUs in the host's datacenter.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the asyncio concepts ! The trivial fix is what i had in the first place, but it looked like the code ran synchronously: linear time in number of calls all prints happening at the same time at the end of the program. But if I understand your answer correctly, that's not an issue with how the code is written